# Replace value with mean of value above and below if value is 20% higher or lower than value above

Tags: r, if-statement, interpolation

I'm trying to clean up time-series data and interpolate values where the sensors malfunctioned in R. I have a column that determines the percent increase of the value from the value above. If that percent difference is greater than 20%, I want to replace that value with the mean of the value above and below. Here is some example data:

```
A        B        Increase
0.2813   0.2813   1%
0.2806   0.2806   0%
0.2736   0.2736  -2%
0.2715   0.2715  -1%
0.2726   0.2726   0%
0.2729   0.2729   0%
0.2701   0.2701  -1%
0.3826   TRUE     22%
0.2726   0.2726  -17%
0.3282   TRUE     20%
0.2673   0.2673   -19%
0.329    TRUE     23%
0.2715   0.2715   -17%
```

So far with my code, I've been able to take column A and if the increase is greater than a specified value, I can replace those values with TRUE in column B. By the end of the code, though I get an error reading "Error in seq.default(r$starts[i] + 1, r$ends[i] - 1, 1) : 'to' must be a finite number". Here is what I have so far:

```
#Replace values above 2% with TRUE
df <- mutate(df, B = ifelse(increase > 2, 'TRUE', 
df$A))

#Set missing for if column B is true 
missing <- which(df$B == 'TRUE')

if(1 %in% missing){
  df$B[1] <- 
head(df$B[which(df$B == 'TRUE')],1)
}
if(nrow(df) %in% missing){
  df$B[nrow(data)] <- 
tail(df$B[which(df$B == 'TRUE')],1)
}

#Find start and ends of each run of TRUE
get_runs <- function(x){
  starts <- which(diff(x) == 1)
  y <- rle(x)
  len <- y$lengths[y$values==TRUE]
  ends <- starts + len+1
  return(list(starts=starts,len=len,ends=ends, i=1:length(starts)))
}

 r <- get_runs(which(df$B == 'TRUE'))


for(i in r$i){
  idx <- seq(r$starts[i]+1,r$ends[i]-1,1)
  df$newcol[idx] <- (df$B[r$starts[i]] + 
df$B[r$ends[i]])/2
}
```

I've been able to do this in Excel, but I want to run all of my code in R so that I can easily go back and edit the code. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `stats::filter` to calculate a rolling average window of length 3 and put it in an `ifelse` for that. First transform the percentage column in something useful by deleting the `%` and dividing by 100 with `gsub`.

```
dat <- transform(dat, incr=as.numeric(gsub('\\%', '', Increase))/100)


transform(dat, B1=ifelse(incr > .02, 
                         as.numeric(stats::filter(B, rep(1/3, 3), sides=2)), 
                         B))
    

#         A      B Increase  incr        B1
# 1  0.2813 0.2813       1%  0.01 0.2813000
# 2  0.2806 0.2806       0%  0.00 0.2806000
# 3  0.2736 0.2736      -2% -0.02 0.2736000
# 4  0.2715 0.2715      -1% -0.01 0.2715000
# 5  0.2726 0.2726       0%  0.00 0.2726000
# 6  0.2729 0.2729       0%  0.00 0.2729000
# 7  0.2701 0.2701      -1% -0.01 0.2701000
# 8  0.3826 0.2701      22%  0.22 0.2709333
# 9  0.2726 0.2726     -17% -0.17 0.2726000
# 10 0.3282 0.2701      20%  0.20 0.2700000
# 11 0.2673 0.2673     -19% -0.19 0.2673000
# 12 0.3290 0.2701      23%  0.23 0.2696333
# 13 0.2715 0.2715     -17% -0.17 0.2715000
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(A = c(0.2813, 0.2806, 0.2736, 0.2715, 0.2726, 
0.2729, 0.2701, 0.3826, 0.2726, 0.3282, 0.2673, 0.329, 0.2715
), B = c(0.2813, 0.2806, 0.2736, 0.2715, 0.2726, 0.2729, 0.2701, 
0.2701, 0.2726, 0.2701, 0.2673, 0.2701, 0.2715), Increase = c("1%", 
"0%", "-2%", "-1%", "0%", "0%", "-1%", "22%", "-17%", "20%", 
"-19%", "23%", "-17%")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```